# How can I insert strings with quotes into Perl DBI queries?

Tags: mysql, perl

What is the preferred way to insert strings that can contain both single and double quotes (",') into MySql using DBI?  For example, `$val1` and `$val2` can contain quotes:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect( ... );
my $sql = "insert into tbl_name(col_one,col_two) values($val1, $val2)";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use a bound query using

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("insert into tbl_name(col_one,col_two) values(?,?)");
$sth->execute($val1, $val2);
```

If you use bound variables, everything is escaped for you.

Update: Changed my example to correspond with the example edited into the question.

Update: I don't know why Adam deleted his answer, but if for some reason you can't use bound variables (aka "placeholders"), you can also use `$dbh->quote($var)` on the variable.  For example:

```
$sql = sprintf "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s",
    $dbh->quote(q("Don't"));
```

Comment: It is generally referred to as using placeholders.

Comment: Placeholders also have the very useful property of protecting against SQL injection attacks.  Use them.  Always.  *Never* place user-supplied data into your queries directly.

Comment: 'executeUpdate' should just be 'execute' (and it's an insert anyway, not an update :-) BTW Adam, quote() is also a good answer, there are times when it is preferable to placeholders. But yes, never use user-supplied data directly in your queries, or suffer the wrath of Bobby Tables.

Comment: @Adam you shouldn't have deleted your answer.  It had some usual information.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `quote()` method.  It will intelligently handle the quoting for you. Example from the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#quote):

```
$sql = sprintf "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s",
            $dbh->quote("Don't");
```

Slightly modified to have both types of quotes:

```
$sql = sprintf "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s",
            $dbh->quote(q("Don't"));
```

Comment: I don't remember why I deleted this answer either.  So I'm undeleting it. :)

Answer (score 2):

One small caveat on the bound placeholders, I build a rather large database-loading script that initially used bound placeholders in an older version of Perl/DBI and found what appears to be a memory leak in the placeholder implementation, so if you're looking at using them in a persistent process/daemon or in a high-volume context you may want to make sure process size doesn't become an issue.  Switching over to building the query strings using the quote() method eliminated the issue for me.

Comment: interesting, although it might just have been the fact that statement handle objects were created explicitly that caused memory management issues in Perl - i.e. memory fragmentation. Perl really isn't very good at reclaiming freed memory...

Answer (score 2):

DBI placeholders are awesome. They shine when you need to execute the same query in a loop.  Consider this:

```
  my $dbh = DBI->connect(...);
  my $name_pairs = get_csv_data("data.csv");
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO t1 (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?)");
  for my $pair (@$name_pairs) {
     unless ($sth->execute(@$pair)) {
         warn($sth->errstr);
     }
  }
```

In this case, having the prepared statement handle is, er, handy.

However, barring this sort of tight-loop cases, I like to see the actual statement that was sent to the server.  This is where I lean heavily on quote and frankly sprintf.

```
   # Here, I am confident about the hash keys, less so about the values
   $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO t1 (%s) VALUES (%s)",
                    join(",", keys(%hash)),
                    join("," map { $dbh->quote($_) } values(%hash))
                  );
   $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
   unless ($sth->execute) {
     warn($sth->{Statement});
   }
```

Note that you do have to set RaiseError => 0 on $dbh so that you can see the SQL that failed, but this has helped me a great deal in the past.

Cheers.

Comment: Unclear why this accurate, polite answer was downvoted, but whatevs.